# Keycloak Invalid redirect uri when client use https

Tags: single-sign-on, zabbix, onelogin

I have deployed keycloak servers on AWS EC2 using Application Loadbalancer with ACM and Docker as per https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak. Also use AWS RDS Mariadb and JDBC_PING.

I have created a saml client.If i configure the "Valid Redirect URIs" with a https://* value, SSO page shows "Invalid Redirect URI", When using http://* it work and can have successful login but redirect fails because of "http".

I have enabled "Require SSL" for "all request" on the Realm setting.

Comment: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/invalid-redirect-uri-for-valid-redirect-uris-with-https/3454

Answer (score 1):

I would tweak advanced Zabbix `$SSO['SETTINGS']` configuration.

See https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/3.4.1/#user-content-settings

I guess `$settings['sp']['attributeConsumingService']` is not guessed correctly by the Zabbix frontend code, because SSL offloading on the ALB.